# ORDER BY Subquery for GROUP BY to JOIN conversion

Tags: mysql, sql

i have this table

```
id |   title   | amount | timestamp
1  |  random1  |   150  | 1313635011
2  |  random2  |   190  | 1313635730
3  |  random2  |   210  | 1313637359
4  |  random2  |   100  | 1313691807
5  |  random3  |   130  | 1313692673
6  |  random4  |   900  | 1313692739
7  |  random4  |   111  | 1313692988
```

i want to get this result (rows with different titles and biggest timestamps):

```
id |   title   | amount | timestamp
1  |  random1  |   150  | 1313635011
4  |  random2  |   100  | 1313691807
5  |  random3  |   130  | 1313692673
7  |  random4  |   111  | 1313692988
```

i have this query.

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY timestamp DESC 
) m GROUP BY title
```

It works as charm but can this be converted to a JOIN statement?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you need? The maximum timestamp for a given title?

Comment: There is only one table, what you want to join?

Comment: the whole row with biggest timestamp for **different** titles.this query works great, but i was curious if it could be converted to JOIN statement

Comment: @inflagranti why,who said that someone cant join a table on itself?

Comment: @rootatwc: And it does NOT work great. It group by `title` and gives you a **more or less random** row for every title.

Comment: OP: Please give us a sample table and the desired output. Make it non-trivial so we can understand what you're talking about well enough to edit your post to be intelligible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be simplified to the following (the `ORDER BY` in the subquery is useless):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
GROUP BY title
```

Why do you think that you need `JOIN`? (Ok, this was resolved by comments).

---

After your comment that you need for every title, the row with biggest timestamp, this would do the work:

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM
    table AS t
  JOIN
    ( SELECT title
           , MAX(timestamp) AS maxts
      FROM table
      GROUP BY title
    ) AS grp
    ON grp.title = t.title
    AND grp.maxts = t.timestamp
ORDER BY t.timestamp DESC
```

---

For the record, your original query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
  ( SELECT * 
    FROM table 
    ORDER BY timestamp DESC 
  ) m
GROUP BY title
```

**might** work as expected, but: **only** in MySQL that allows you to use in the `SELECT` list fields that are not in the `GROUP BY` clause (or depend on those), without any aggregate functions in them. So, the above query will return a **more or less random** row for every title. In fact, it will return the first row it will find for a title. So, having first run the subquery (which orders by `timestamp DESC`) results in finding first the row with biggest timestamp.

This however, only happens because (when, if) the optimizer does not understand that the subquery is useless. You may find that your original query runs fine when one day you upgrade to MySQL version 7.5 and your query stops working as before. (because the optimizer got more clever and translated your query to a simpler without sub-select).

You may even find your query to stop working altogether and produce error if MySQL decides in a future release to be in terms with SQL standards for the `GROUP BY` queries.

Comment: Yes,i need it ordered by the biggest timestamp..this will give me the result with the exactly opposite order

Comment: So, add an `ORDER BY t.timestamp DESC`

Comment: thanks ypercube, you are absolutely right, i kinda understood that group by is pretty much random in MySQL and moreover my query didn't fit to my head,that's why i asked SO's help!
thanks again

Answer (score 0):

The sql statement is invalid.

ORDER BY is invalid in an subquery

GROUP BY needs an aggregate function, like COUNT, SUM etc.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table
GROUP BY title
ORDER BY title
```

Comment: And `SELECT title FROM table GROUP BY title` is valid SQL (in general).

Comment: OK, I see the mysql tag now.  Good to know.  The query above refuses to run in SQL Server.

Comment: @ypercube - select * from table group by title, will not run in SQL Server, but select title from table group by title will.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Yes, it's a "feature" of MySQL. It's actually useful in some situations though.