# Get the entire row of the maximum value of a column in every category

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table containing news posts and would like to get the entire last added **newspost** of every category.
The table contains these columns:

- id, title, images, description, category, date

Example: I have 20 posts in 3 categories. The last post by date of every category is returned so I get 3 posts back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

think the smallest and most usable solution for this is that one:

```
SELECT * FROM ( 
   SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY date DESC
) as t
GROUP BY t.category;
```

an other approach will be the group having with subquery...

@eggyal:
This will use the LASTEST inserted with max_date, because of the internal sortorder of the rdbms...

Comment: 1. group by is affected by the order of the incoming set in mysql... - have a test-run before pointing that out..
2. ALL columns are affected by the group - this is the purpose of grouping; you group by category and it will use the first "sub-result" in group to display, in that case: the last newspost...
3. i tested it already - this is quite simple, but if you really want the banging solution, i'll add that one...

Comment: This behaviour cannot be relied upon.  As [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html) says: "*The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate.*"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7114173/order-by-subquery-for-group-by-to-join-conversion

Comment: Exactly. Not only is ypercube's analysis absolutely correct, but it could also be that there's a `HASH` index on `category` which gets used for the grouping operation: this would discard any ordering performed in the subquery, which could itself get optimised away in a future version of MySQL.  You really shouldn't rely on such undocumented and unsupported behaviour.

Comment: because of that, and to be really correct, i edited your solution and added limiting to one-result per group with grouping again the result-set...
i'm totally on your side, but i thought, that this will be not "as easy" as the silly solution of me -- if he want's to modify the query, he has to get, what's going on here... without any description on `NATURAL JOIN` or joins in a general matter, he will be maybe stuck again on some point...

Comment: If you apply another `GROUP BY`, as you propose, for each category you'll select a single indeterminate record from those with the latest date: who is to say whether that's correct behaviour?  It may not even be consistent.  Better to handle this edge case in one's application code, or else define an ordering that encompasses a `UNIQUE` column.

Comment: okay... you're really obstinate...
so we have to group again with MAX(id) and produce the next nested subquery instead of just saying "okay - just give me ONE of two, three or five daily posts"

it's the author's choice imho.

Comment: Works like a charm, I had something like this in mind but had the same concerns as eggyal with server behaviour. Though, I tested it several times and it is probably the simplest solution (probably fastest as well)
Thanks TheHe and eggyal

Answer (score 1):

You want the [groupwise maximum](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html):

```
SELECT newsposts.* FROM newsposts NATURAL JOIN (
  SELECT category, MAX(date) AS date FROM newsposts GROUP BY category
) t
```

Comment: not will actually return the right result...

it will group by category but will not select the "title, images, description and id" for the corresponding MAX(date)...

it will only get the right DATE in group...

Comment: @TheHe: Err, that's what the subquery will do... the parent query then joins the `newsposts` table with that subquery to obtain the rest of the columns.

Comment: oh yeah! you're TOTALLY right...
but... when there are TWO newspost on the same day and category, BOTH will be displayed ;)

Comment: @TheHe: Errr... how else do you determine the "latest" post?

Comment: check out mine... quick'n'dirty?

Comment: added limiting to your (better) solution.