# Set the default schema order of a MySQL table to be reversed

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am currently running this query:

```
SELECT t.videolink, t.userid, t.tag
    FROM (SELECT * FROM tagstrend ORDER BY timestamp DESC) AS t
        WHERE t.timestamp > ?
        GROUP BY t.tag
        ORDER BY SUM(t.tagcount) DESC
        LIMIT ?, 20;
```

What I am doing is reversing the order of the table that I am selecting from before I run the rest of the query because when the I use "GROUP BY" I need that to take the top result which is the most recent row in the database.

However doing this will take a hit on the performance/speed of the query because it needs to reverse the order of the table before it can query it.

My question is, is there a way to set the default order of the table to be reversed? Because I will always be SELECTing from this table in reverse order.

Unless someone knows a way of grouping by the most recent row in the database?

Comment: Why are you calling `SELECT` on a `SELECT *` instead of just writing a single call that does what you want?

Comment: Because I need the whole table, I just need it in reverse order @tadman

Comment: The order of your result has nothing to do with the order of the original table, since you're ordering by an aggregate function.

Comment: So are you saying the way I am doing it now would be the only way to do it? @Barmar

Comment: Are you asking about `ORDER BY timestamp` in the subquery? I don't think that has any effect on your result, since you're summing all the rows in each group.

Comment: A table in a relational database has ***no*** order. The question "*reversing the order of the table*" does not make sense. Only results of `select` statements can have an order (and only if an `order by` was specified).

Comment: @Barmar: I think the OP is trying to use this undocumented feature of MySQL whereby the returned value of a column that is neither aggregated nor included in GROUP BY is the one encountered *first* in the group's row set. So, they are selecting from a dataset *pre-ordered* in a specific way, to get the desired results. Again, that's not documented but that, at least, is what the OP seems to be doing in their query. See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7114235 "ORDER BY Subquery for GROUP BY to JOIN conversion") for an alternative explanation, for I'm not sure mine is clear enough.

Comment: Yes @Andriy M that is exactly what I meant! It is an undocumented feature the GROUP BY groups the first row occurrence of each value so the first value with "foo" and other id "1234" will always show up for grouping by "foo". But I want the most recent "foo" which has an id in the table as "5678". I want "5678" not the "1234"

Comment: When grouping, use `MAX` or `MIN` functions rather than depending on what's more like a bug in MySQL than a feature.

Comment: How could I use the MAX and MIN function in a GROUP BY when I want to just group by 'tag' but I want the MAX timestamp? @tadman

Comment: Yeah, you can do multiple operations at the same time on the things that are grouped. If you want the first or last element of some kind, use `MIN` or `MAX` accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"However doing this will take a hit on the performance/speed of the query because it needs to reverse the order of the table before it can query it."

I don't think that is true.  Order By .... ASC and Order By .... DESC should have the same performance.  Test it and see.